# Adding date.now to a controller with code allready inside it

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I have the following code in my controller:

```
// GET: /Review/Create
public ActionResult Create()
    {
        var userGames = db.tblGames.Where(g => g.UserName == User.Identity.Name);
        ViewBag.GameIDFK = new SelectList(userGames, "GameID", "GameName");
        return View(new tblReview { UserName = @User.Identity.Name });
    }
```

// POST: /Review/Create

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(tblReview tblreview)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.tblReviews.Add(tblreview);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        var userGames = db.tblGames.Where(g => g.UserName == User.Identity.Name);
        ViewBag.GameIDFK = new SelectList(userGames, "GameID", "GameName");
        return View(new tblReview { UserName = @User.Identity.Name });
    }
```

And i want to add this line of code to it:

```
        return View(new tblReview { Posted = DateTime.Now });
```

But i dont know how to combine the code together. I have tried a If statement but the application fell apart as in it was just throwing errors everywhere.

The reason i want to add these to codes together is so when a review is written the viewer can see the date the review was posted. I have a posted attribute in my database table and model for that looks like this:

```
namespace TestWebSite.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class tblReview
    {
        public int ReviewID { get; set; }
        public string Recomendation { get; set; }
        public string AvoidOrBuy { get; set; }
        public string Score { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime Posted { get; set; }
        public int GameIDFK { get; set; }
        public string UserName { get; set; }

        public virtual tblGame tblGame { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Thank you

If you require addtional information please ask me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I admint that I don't understand extactly the relation form `tblReview` and `NewsItem`, but if you want to expose that information without setting it in the ViewModel, I think the only way is to use the ViewBag.

Something like

```
ViewBag.NewsItem = new NewsItem() { Posted = DateTime.Now };
```

and then accessing it from the view.

I honestly would create a specific viewmodel holding all the information the view needs, but if there is not other way I guess this is an alternative.

**Update**

After the change you made I don't see why this should not work

```
return View(new tblReview { UserName = @User.Identity.Name, Posted = DateTime.Now });
```

Comment: oh sorry that was the wrong table name thanks for that i will edit it you have keen eyes. I got the code from my first project and was trying to impliment it but i forgot to change the name of it when i posted the question thank you, will try this and let you know

Comment: I have added ur code it complies so it must be somthing am doing wrong. The date is not getting showing on the page when i run it. Is there somthing i have to add to the view?

Comment: I don't know what you are doing in your view, but try to simply put a @Html.TextboxFor(model => model.Posted) somewhere in the view and see what is the html. Otherwise you should post your view code so we can help

Comment: Ur update has slightly confused me sorry, where does the view bag go? controller or view?

Comment: You said my update compile correctly, so you don't need the viewbag anymore. In your view you should have your model populated correctly. So I was saying to use a simple html.textboxfor to see the output in the html. (you should see your field `posted` correctly)

Comment: Ahhh ok understand, will try and then let you know of outcome thanks

Comment: Thank you worked spot on :) thanks marked up answer and ticked it as correct